# Оптимизация .load()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно с одной страницы загружать версии софта на сайт (несколько мест). Строго не судите за костыли, не знаю JS, делаю простые вещи по аналогии с C++. Пока делаю таким образом:

```
<script>
     $( "#v1" ).load( "/vr.html #v1" );
     $( "#v2" ).load( "/vr.html #v2" );
     $( "#v3" ).load( "/vr.html #v3" );
     $( "#v4" ).load( "/vr.html #v4" );
     $( "#v5" ).load( "/vr.html #v5" );
     $( "#v6" ).load( "/vr.html #v6" );
     $( "#v7" ).load( "/vr.html #v7" );
     $( "#v8" ).load( "/vr.html #v8" );
     $( "#v9" ).load( "/vr.html #v9" );
     $( "#v10" ).load( "/vr.html #v10" );
     $( "#v11" ).load( "/vr.html #v11" );
     $( "#v12" ).load( "/vr.html #v12" );
     $( "#v13" ).load( "/vr.html #v13" );
     $( "#v14" ).load( "/vr.html #v14" );
</script>
```

**Как это можно оптимизировать?**

Comment: А в C++ нет циклов?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, избавится от загрузки страницы 14 раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если с циклами

```
 var linkCount = 14;
 for(var i = 1; i <= linkCount; i++) {
     $( "#v" + i ).load( "/vr.html #v" + i );
 }
```

Если же хотите, что бы не было кучи обращений к серверу, тогда сделайте что-нибудь на подобии этого:

```
function loadData(url) {
    var tempEl = $("<div>"); // создаем виртуальный DOM элемент
    tempEl.load(url); // загружаем в него данные один раз
    var linkCount = 14;
    for(var i = 1; i <= linkCount; i++) {
        // берем данные из виртуального элемента
        $( "#v" + i ).html( tempEl.find("#v" + i) ); 
    }
}

//Используем
loadData("/vr.html");
```